# Generate a strongly-typed proxy that can track changes on property names not values when one property is set to another

Tags: c#, proxy, change-tracking

**Setup:**

```cs
public class Data
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}

public class Runner
{
    public static void Run(Data data)
    {
        data.A = data.B;
        data.A = 1;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new Data() { A = 1, B = 2 };
        Runner.Run(data);
    }
}
```

**Problem:** I need to implement change tracking here for property names not values. Inside `Runner.Run` on the first line `data.A = data.B` I need to record somehow that "A" was set to "B" (*literally property names*) and then on the next line `data.A = 1` I need to record that "A" was set to constant and say forget about it.

Constrains:

- When setting one property to another (e.g. A = B) that needs to be recorded
- When setting property to anything else (e.g. A = 1 or A = B * 2) this change needs to be forgotten (e.g. remember A only)

Suppose this is the tracker contract being used:

```cs
void RecordChange(string setterName, string getterName);
void UnTrackChange(string setterName);
```

**Question:**
I would like to somehow proxy the `Data` class so it still can be used in the interface code (e.g. `Runner` - is a whole bunch of a business logic code that uses `Data`) INCLUDING strong-typing and it can track it's changes without modifying the code (e.g. there is lots of places like 'data.A = data.B').

Is there any way to do it without resorting to I guess some magic involving IL generation?

**Already investigated/tried:**

- PostSharp interceptors/Castle.DynamicProxy with interceptors - these alone cannot help. The most I can get out of it is to have a value of `data.B` inside setter interceptor but not `nameof(data.B)`.
- Compiler services - haven't found anything suitable here - getting the name of caller doesn't really help.
- Runtine code generation - smth like proxy inherited from DynamicObject or using Relfection.Emit (TypeBuilder probably) - I lose typings.

Current solution:

Use the Tracker implementation of the abovementioned contract and pass it around into every function down the road. Then instead of writing `data.A = data.B` use method `tracker.SetFrom(x => x.A, x => x.B)` - tracker holds a `Data` instance and so this works. BUT in a real codebase it is easy to miss something and it just makes it way less readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the closest the solution I've come up with. It isn't perfect as I still need to modify all the contracts/methods in the client code to use a new data model but at least all the logic stays the same.

So I'm open for other answers.

Here's the renewed `Data` model:

```cs
public readonly struct NamedProperty<TValue>
{
    public NamedProperty(string name, TValue value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public TValue Value { get; }

    public static implicit operator TValue (NamedProperty<TValue> obj)
        => obj.Value;

    public static implicit operator NamedProperty<TValue>(TValue value)
        => new NamedProperty<TValue>(null, value);
}

public interface ISelfTracker<T> 
    where T : class, ISelfTracker<T>
{
    Tracker<T> Tracker { get; set; }
}

public class NamedData : ISelfTracker<NamedData>
{
    public virtual NamedProperty<int> A { get; set; }
    public virtual NamedProperty<int> B { get; set; }

    public Tracker<NamedData> Tracker { get; set; }
}
```

Basically I've copy-pasted the original `Data` model but changed all its properties to be aware of their names.

Then the tracker itself:

```cs
public class Tracker<T> 
    where T : class, ISelfTracker<T>
{
    public T Instance { get; }
    public T Proxy { get; }

    public Tracker(T instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
        Proxy = new ProxyGenerator().CreateClassProxyWithTarget<T>(Instance, new TrackingNamedProxyInterceptor<T>(this));
        Proxy.Tracker = this;
    }

    public void RecordChange(string setterName, string getterName)
    {
    }

    public void UnTrackChange(string setterName)
    {
    }
}
```

The interceptor for Castle.DynamicProxy:

```cs
public class TrackingNamedProxyInterceptor<T> : IInterceptor
    where T : class, ISelfTracker<T>
{
    private const string SetterPrefix = "set_";
    private const string GetterPrefix = "get_";

    private readonly Tracker<T> _tracker;

    public TrackingNamedProxyInterceptor(Tracker<T> proxy)
    {
        _tracker = proxy;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (IsSetMethod(invocation.Method))
        {
            string propertyName = GetPropertyName(invocation.Method);
            dynamic value = invocation.Arguments[0];

            var propertyType = value.GetType();
            if (IsOfGenericType(propertyType, typeof(NamedProperty<>)))
            {
                if (value.Name == null)
                {
                    _tracker.UnTrackChange(propertyName);
                }
                else
                {
                    _tracker.RecordChange(propertyName, value.Name);
                }

                var args = new[] { propertyName, value.Value };
                invocation.Arguments[0] = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType, args);
            }
        }

        invocation.Proceed();
    }

    private string GetPropertyName(MethodInfo method)
        => method.Name.Replace(SetterPrefix, string.Empty).Replace(GetterPrefix, string.Empty);

    private bool IsSetMethod(MethodInfo method)
        => method.IsSpecialName && method.Name.StartsWith(SetterPrefix);

    private bool IsOfGenericType(Type type, Type openGenericType)
        => type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openGenericType;
}
```

And the modified entry point:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = new Data() { A = 1, B = 2 };
    NamedData namedData = Map(data);
    var proxy = new Tracker<NamedData>(namedData).Proxy;
    Runner.Run(proxy);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The `Map()` function actually maps `Data` to `NamedData` filling in property names.